# dispaying the data of /odom (nav_msgs/Odometry) UTM-encoded position in RVIZ

Tags: navigation, odometry, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Fuerte on Ubuntu 12.04

The goal is to display the odometry of the robot in RVIZ.

I am using the Xsens-mtig gps imu module. I used the package cyphy_xsens_mtig package which publishes /fix and then gps_common package which subscribes to /fix and publishes /odom (nav_msgs/Odometry) which is a UTM-encoded position.

I launched RVIZ and and selected the /base_imu frame id . The odometry display type in rviz shows that the messages are being received but i am not able to see the GPS location in rviz. I have tried all the views possible but it just shows a line which is a reference to TF.

I guess that some link is missing between the TF of GPS and UTM..If any one has any idea, please let me know

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42842/dispaying-the-data-of---/odom-(nav_msgs/odometry)----utm-encoded-position--in-rviz/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2012-09-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Got the answer. The gps_common package does not publish any TF data. So I have added a TF broadcaster and am able to view the TF data in RVIZ.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2012-09-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0